# change the color of the div depending on the value of the variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to change the color of my card depending on the value of the variable

How can i do this?

I thought you could do this?

```
getStyles(key: number) {
    let color = ''
    if (number < 40) {color = 'red';}
    else if (number >= 40 && number < 80) {color = 'yellow';}
    else (number >= 80) {color = 'green';}
    return {
      color: color
    };
}

<div class="p-a-1 bg-warning" [ngStyle]="getStyles(40)">
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Or can this be done using a pipe?

But if it can be done through a pipe, then I do not quite understand how

What is the best practice?

Comment: This functionality will be used in different components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could i.e using a directive like

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[colors]'
})
export class ColorsDirective implements OnInit{
  @Input() colors: number;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    const current = this._getStyles(this.colors);
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      'color',
      current
    );
  }
  _getStyles(key: number) {
    let color = '';
    if (key < 40) {
      color = 'red';
    }
    else if (key >= 40 && key < 80) {
      color = 'yellow';
    }
    else  {
      color = 'green';
    }
    return  color;
  }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
<p [colors]="40">PIPPO</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a small change by doing something like this:

```
<div class="p-a-1 bg-warning" [ngStyle]="{'color': getStyles(40)}">
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

And changing your getStyles method to return the color and not an object.

Comment: Well, so normal and the pipe is not needed? Simply if it is necessary for me in different components, then copy this function as something not very good

Answer (score 2):

Extending the answer of @Thatkookooguy

You can create a common function in the service and call it from each component by importing them into the component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class CommonService {

  getClassBasedOnKey(key: any) {
    if (key < 40) {
      return 'red';
    } else if (key >= 40 && key < 80) {
      return 'yellow';
    }
    return 'green';
  }
}
```

Now importing the service into the module in the provider:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [],
  providers: [ CommonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

And using it in the component and HTML:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public _commonService: CommonService) {

  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="p-a-1 bg-warning" [ngClass]="_commonService.getClassBasedOnKey(40)">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps....Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

`else` is followed by a condition without `if`.

Replace this line

```
else (number >= 80) {color = 'green';}
```

by either

```
else {color = 'green';}
```

or

```
else if (number >= 80) {color = 'green';}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have added a class based on the key instead of actually adding the color. this solution allows you to attach additional changes to the class.

here's the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l4tcxs

basically, there are 3 classes (one for each color), and the code adds the class based on the string in `color`

```js
// COMPONENT YOU WANT TO USE IN
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  getClassBasedOnKey
} from './shared-functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  getClassBasedOnKey: Function = getClassBasedOnKey;
}

// shared-functions.ts
export function getClassBasedOnKey(key: number) {
  if (key < 40) {
    return 'red';
  } else if (key >= 40 && key < 80) {
    return 'yellow';
  }
  return 'green';
}
```

```css
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
  background: black;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-a-1 bg-warning" [ngClass]="getClassBasedOnKey(40)">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In other components, I have to duplicate this function. How can I take it out and use it many times?

Comment: @cat1244 if you separate that function to a different typescript file, you can just import it and use it everywhere (you just need to attach it to the component as well for it to be reachable through the `HTML`). I changed my answer to reflect your case

Comment: @cat1244 if this helped, don't forget to mark as the right answer ;-)